# unable to get the services+notifications in android

Tags: android, service, notifications

I have an Android application that connects to a database. I would like to write a background thread to continuously update data from the database, and i want to show that updated data as notificaton how can i do that? for example in skype if we get new message we will get notification right ..like that i want to do...can some body help me??

Comment: what you have tried?where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done as follows way. Your `Activity` should contain the following:

```
//the method which changes the data in the database
changeDataBD(params) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() { 
        changingDataDB(params);
    }).start();
}

//create an handler
private final Handler myHandler = new Handler();

private void changingDataDB(params) {
    //.... changing of data in DB according to passed params

    //update the UI using the handler and the runnable
    myHandler.post(updateRunnable);

}

final Runnable updateRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //call the activity method that updates the UI
        updateUIandShowNotification();
    }
};

private void updateUIandShowNotification() {
      // ... update the data on UI
      // ... show a notification
}
```

You can also create a listener that will monitor changes in the database. And it should starts this thread.